# What does this icon with a dart and two stars stand for in Bloons TD 6?

Tags: bloons-td-6

This icon is present on a few of my maps, indicating the same three towers, a Village, a Spike Factory, and a Wizard Monkey:

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out what it means though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the symbol for [Monkey Teams](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Monkey_Teams_(BTD6)). You get extra money if you beat the level using only those towers.

Another symbol you'll sometimes see on that screen is the [Golden Bloon](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Golden_Bloon_(BTD6)), which sometimes launches a special, extra-tough bloon that gives extra money for defeating it.

You'll never see both specials on the same level.  According to the wiki,

> [Monkey Teams and Golden Bloons] will alternate every 2 days, every two 8:00pm NZST days to be specific.

Comment: Thx I was quite confused by it